# Sliding footer with content in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I wanted to know that how do I make the below page where the footer(Like, Comment, Share, Shave) remains in the bottom till the length of the content and when the content is over while sliding the footer(Like, Comment, Share, Shave) slides up with its own content.
as shown in the below 2 images.
Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: but that is a simple scroll and here I want to scroll according to the content.

Comment: do you get the idea of how I want it? its like dragging the page vertically and as the content is over the footer also gets dragged up.